# How to grab an arbitrary chunk from a file on Unix/Linux

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to copy a chunk from one binary file into a new file. I have the byte offset and length of the chunk I want to grab.

I have tried using the `dd` utility, but this seems to read and discard the data up to the offset, rather than just seeking (I guess because `dd` is for copying/converting blocks of data). This makes it quite slow (and slower the higher the offset). This is the command I tried:

```
dd if=inputfile ibs=1 skip=$offset count=$datalength of=outputfile
```

I guess I could write a small Perl/Python/whatever script to open the file, seek to the offset, then read and write the required amount of data in chunks.

Is there a utility that supports something like this?

Comment: I just tried running `strace` on dd, it used llseek.

Comment: Ah, I'm on freebsd, so maybe it's a different implementation. Maybe it is slow because I set the input buffer size to 1 byte.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's awkward to do this with dd today. We're considering adding skip_bytes and count_bytes params to dd in coreutils to help. The following should work though:

```
#!/bin/sh

bs=100000
infile=$1
skip=$2
length=$3

(
  dd bs=1 skip=$skip count=0
  dd bs=$bs count=$(($length / $bs))
  dd bs=$(($length % $bs)) count=1
) < "$infile"
```

Comment: Yeah, adding skip/count_bytes would be really useful, and make dd an easy-to-use general purpose byte-grabber :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `tail -c+N` to trim the leading N bytes from input, then you can use `head -cM` to output only the first M bytes from its input.

```
$ echo "hello world 1234567890" | tail -c+9 | head -c6
rld 12
```

So using your variables, it would probably be:

```
tail -c+$offset inputfile | head -c$datalength > outputfile
```

---

Ah, didn't see it had to seek.  Leaving this as community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the other answers. Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to install additional software, so the ddrescue option is out. The head/tail solution is interesting (I didn't realise you could supply + to tail), but scanning through the data makes it quite slow.

I ended up writing a small python script to do what I wanted. The buffer size should probably be tuned to be the same as some external buffer setting, but using the value below is performant enough on my system.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import sys

BUFFER_SIZE = 100000

# Read args
if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: %s input_file start_pos length" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit(1)
input_filename = sys.argv[1]
start_pos = int(sys.argv[2])
length = int(sys.argv[3])

# Open file and seek to start pos
input = open(sys.argv[1])
input.seek(start_pos)

# Read and write data in chunks
while length > 0:
    # Read data
    buffer = input.read(min(BUFFER_SIZE, length))
    amount_read = len(buffer)

    # Check for EOF
    if not amount_read:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Reached EOF, exiting..."
        sys.exit(1)

    # Write data
    sys.stdout.write(buffer)
    length -= amount_read
```

Comment: The buffer size should be large enough to keep the number of syscalls (and context switches) down, and a multiple of the page size to make the caching as happy as possible. Kernel readahead means that it won't likely have any real effect on the size of the disk I/Os requested. 100000 isn't a multiple of 4kiB, but values from 64kiB to 1MiB are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
--input-position=POS
```

option of [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to [`man` `dd` on FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dd&sektion=1):

> `skip=`*n*
>
> > Skip *n* blocks from the beginning of the input before copying.
> >     **On input which supports seeks, an lseek(2) operation is used.**
> >     Otherwise, input data is read and discarded.  For pipes, the
> >     correct number of bytes is read.  For all other devices, the
> >     correct number of blocks is read without distinguishing between
> >     a partial or complete block being read.

Using `dtruss` I verified that it does use `lseek()` on an input file on Mac OS X.
If you just think that it is slow then I agree with the comment that this would be due to the 1-byte block size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hexdump command :

```
 hexdump  -v <File Path> -c -n <No of bytes to read> -s <Start Offset> | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | sed 's/ //g'
```

Ex.) Read 100 bytes from 'mycorefile' starting from offset 100.

```
# hexdump  -v -c  mycorefile -n 100 -s 100 | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | sed 's/ //g'
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
\0\0\0\0001\0\0\0005\0\0\0\0020003\0
\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 003\0
\0\0\0\0\0020\0\0\0\0\0\0001\0\0\0
006\0\0\0\0020003\0\0\0\0\0\0220c\0
\0\0\0\0
```

Then, using another script join all the lines of the output into single line if you want.

If you simply want to see the contents :

```
# /usr/bin/hexdump  -v -C  mycorefile -n 100 -s 100
00000064  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000074  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  05 00 00 00 00 10 03 00  |................|
00000084  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......@.........|
00000094  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 a0 03 00  |................|
000000a4  00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
000000b4  06 00 00 00 00 10 03 00  00 00 00 00 00 90 63 00  |..............c.|
000000c4  00 00 00 00                                       |....|
000000c8
#
```