# How do I extract a single chunk of bytes from within a file?

Tags: linux, file, split

On a Linux desktop (RHEL4) I want to extract a range of bytes (typically less than 1000) from within a large file (>1 Gig). I know the offset into the file and the size of the chunk.

I can write code to do this but is there a command line solution?

Ideally, something like:

```
magicprogram --offset 102567 --size 253 < input.binary > output.binary
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try [`dd`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html):

```
dd skip=102567 count=253 if=input.binary of=output.binary bs=1
```

The option `bs=1` sets the block size, making `dd` read and write one byte at a time. The default block size is 512 bytes.

The value of `bs` also affects the behavior of `skip` and `count` since the numbers in `skip` and `count` are the *numbers of blocks* that `dd` will skip and read/write, respectively.

Comment: Optionally add `status=none` to suppress outputting to stderr.

Comment: Here is example using hex offsets: `dd if=in.bin bs=1 status=none skip=$((0x88)) count=$((0x80)) of=out.bin`.

Comment: @kenorb: I believe the hex syntax is part of Bash, so it doesn't necessarily work with other shells. I myself use tcsh (don't hit me!) and your example doesn't work there.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use bs=1 and count=253 and not the other way round? Would the larger block size make the command more efficient?

Comment: @rexford: The skip number is also given in blocks, and is not a multiple of 253. And given that the OS does its own buffering when reading from a normal file on a file system, in this case efficiency will not be as bas as when reading from a device.

Comment: but I don't want to calc the `count`, I only known the start and end offset.

Comment: Could you explain the parameters?

Comment: bs=1 is loads slower than, say, bs=1000 though. I actually saw a factor of 500 in a short test.

Answer (score 84):

This is an old question, but I'd like to add another version of the [`dd`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) command that is better-suited for large chunks of bytes:

```
dd if=input.binary of=output.binary skip=$offset count=$bytes iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes
```

where `$offset` and `$bytes` are numbers in byte units.

The difference with Thomas's accepted answer is that `bs=1` does not appear here. `bs=1` sets the input and output block size to 1 byte, which makes it terribly slow when the number of bytes to extract is large.

This means we leave the block size (`bs`) at its default of 512 bytes. Using `iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes`, we tell `dd` to treat the values after `skip` and `count` as byte amount instead of block amount.

Comment: This is indeed very much faster than my answer.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac - `iflag` is an unknown operand and without it you get an entire block.

Comment: @Timmmm GNU `dd` can be used for `iflag` support (`brew install coreutils`). Note: by default the utilities are installed with a `g` prefix (e.g. `gdd` instead of `dd`)

Answer (score 16):

**`head -c` + `tail -c`**

Not sure how it compares to `dd` in efficiency, but it is fun:

```
printf "123456789" | tail -c+2 | head -c3
```

picks 3 bytes, starting at the 2nd one:

```
234
```

See also:

- [How to grab an arbitrary chunk from a file on Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1272995/895245)
- [Manual for head](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html)
- [Manual for tail](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

Comment: @elvis.dukaj yes, there should be no different. Just give it a try with `printf '\x01\x02' > f` and `hd`.

Comment: Much faster than dd with bs=1, thank you! Please note that tail counts bytes from 1, not from 0. Also, tail exits with error code 1 when its output is closed prematurely by head. Make sure to ignore that error when using "set -e".

Answer (score 2):

Even faster

```
dd bs=<req len> count=1 skip=<req offset> if=input.binary of=output.binary
```

Comment: The problem here is that `skip` is in units of `bs`.

Comment: it is a detail for the executor, and still better than the above, true you'd need to re-calc like: `req_offset=$(bc <<< "$offset/$bs")` and make sure it turns out a round value.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, trying to cut parts of a RAW disk image.
dd with bs=1 is unusable, therefore I have made a simple C program for the task.

```
// usage:
//  ./cutfile srcfile destfile offset length
//  ./cutfile my.image movie.avi 4524 20412452
// compile, presuming it is saved as cutfile.cc:
//  gcc cutfile.cc -o cutfile -std=c11 -pedantic -W -Wall -Werror 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc != 5) {
      printf("error, need 4 arguments!\n");
      return 1;
  }


  const unsigned blocksize = 16*512;  // can adjust
  unsigned char buffer[blocksize];

  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  FILE *fout = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
  long offset = atol(argv[3]);
  long length = atol(argv[4]);
  if(f==NULL || fout==NULL) {
      perror("cannot open file");
      return 1;
  }
  fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET);

  while(length > blocksize) {
      fread(buffer, 1, blocksize, f);
      fwrite(buffer, 1, blocksize, fout);
      length -= blocksize;
  }
  if(length>0) { // copy rest
      fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
      fwrite(buffer, 1, length, fout);
  }    

  fclose(fout);
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that in C++ you're kind of expected to use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`...

Comment: yes, but actually it's pure C if I change includes like cstdio to stdio.h .
I don't know why I chose to start with C++ headers, maybe I have thought I will use more C++ stuff at first?!

Comment: Yeah, you may want to edit your answer and make it C since the OP asked about C.

Answer (score 1):

The dd command can do all of this.  Look at the seek and/or skip parameters as part of the call.

Comment: but dd can be very slow when you want blick missaligned access. and doing bs=1 is super slow

Answer (score 0):

I run into this use case so much that I created a pair of bash functions to do this, called `crunch` and `munch`. `crunch` accepts start and end offsets, extracting a specific range, while `munch` accepts one offset and extracts bytes from either the head or tail of a file. They use `head` and `tail` under the hood and let you specify the offsets in hex or decimal format.

Usage examples:

- `crunch input.binary 102567 $((102567+253))`
- `crunch myfile.bin 0x1000 0x2000`
- `munch head myfile.bin 0x100`
- `munch tail myfile.bin 224892`

```bash
crunch() {
  if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "usage: crunch <file.bin> <start address> <end address>"
    echo ""
    echo "example: crunch myfile.bin 0x1000 0x2000"
  else
    local file="$1"
    local start_addr="$2"
    local end_addr="$3"
    local difference="$(($end_addr - $start_addr))"
    local out_name="${file%%.*}_crunch.${file#*.}"
    echorun_conf "tail -c +$(($start_addr+1)) $file | head -c $difference > $out_name"
  fi
}

munch() {
  if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "usage: munch <(head|tail)> <file.bin> <offset>"
    echo ""
    echo "example: munch head myfile.bin 0x100"
  else
    local op="$1"
    local file="$2"
    local offset="$3"
    local out_name="${file%%.*}_munch.${file#*.}"
    case "$op" in
      "head") echorun_conf "head -c $((offset)) $file > $out_name" ;;
      "tail") echorun_conf "tail -c +$((offset+1)) $file > $out_name" ;;
      *)
      echo "usage: munch <(head|tail)> <file.bin> <offset>"
      echo ""
      echo "example: munch head myfile.bin 0x100" ;;
    esac
  fi
}

# echo and run command with y/n confirmation
echorun_conf() {
  echo "$@"
  echo -n "Execute [y/n]? "
  read reply
  echo
  if [ "$reply" != "${reply#[Yy]}" ]; then
    eval "$@"
  fi
}
```