# Read a file by bytes in BASH

Tags: bash

I need to read first byte of file I specified, then second byte,third and so on. How could I do it on BASH?
P.S I need to get HEX of this bytes

Comment: do you need HEX fro each byte ?

Comment: A a bin and hex for each byte of file

Comment: superset, random access: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423346/how-do-i-extract-a-single-chunk-of-bytes-from-within-a-file

Answer (score 41, accepted):

##### Full rewrite: september 2019!

A lot shorter and simplier than previous versions! (Something faster, but not so much)

## Yes , [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) can read and write binary:

Syntax:

```
LANG=C IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 foo
```

will populate `$foo` with 1 binary byte. Unfortunately, as bash strings cannot hold null bytes ($`\0`), reading *one byte once* is required.

> If `read` command success and `$foo` is empty, then read byte is *NULL*. Else, `$foo` will hold THE byte read in binary form.

Then for the *value* of byte read, ( I've missed this in `man bash`, have a look at 2016 post, at bottom of this ;b) :

```
printf -v value %d \`$byte
```

> ```
>  printf [-v var] format [arguments]
>  ...
>      Arguments to non-string format specifiers are treated as C constants,
>      except that ..., and if  the leading character is a  single or double
>      quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character.
> ```

So:

```
read8() {
    local _r8_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r8_car LANG=C IFS=
    read -r -d '' -n 1 _r8_car
    printf -v $_r8_var %d \'$_r8_car
}
```

Will populate submitted variable name (default to `$OUTBIN`) with decimal ascii value of first byte from STDIN

```
read16() {
    local _r16_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r16_lb _r16_hb
    read8 _r16_lb &&
    read8 _r16_hb
    printf -v $_r16_var %d $(( _r16_hb<<8 | _r16_lb ))
}
```

Will populate submitted variable name (default to `$OUTBIN`) with decimal value of first 16 bits word from STDIN...

Of course, for switching [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), you have to switch:

```
    read8 _r16_hb &&
    read8 _r16_lb
```

And so on:

```
# Usage:
#       read[8|16|32|64] [varname] < binaryStdInput

read8() {  local _r8_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r8_car LANG=C IFS=
    read -r -d '' -n 1 _r8_car
    printf -v $_r8_var %d "'"$_r8_car ;}
read16() { local _r16_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r16_lb _r16_hb
    read8  _r16_lb && read8  _r16_hb
    printf -v $_r16_var %d $(( _r16_hb<<8 | _r16_lb )) ;}
read32() { local _r32_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r32_lw _r32_hw
    read16 _r32_lw && read16 _r32_hw
    printf -v $_r32_var %d $(( _r32_hw<<16| _r32_lw )) ;}
read64() { local _r64_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r64_ll _r64_hl
    read32 _r64_ll && read32 _r64_hl
    printf -v $_r64_var %d $(( _r64_hl<<32| _r64_ll )) ;}
```

#### Sample playing with *GPT* patitions tables.

So you could `source` this, then if your `/dev/sda` is `gpt` partitioned,

```
read totsize < <(blockdev --getsz /dev/sda)
read64 gptbackup < <(dd if=/dev/sda bs=8 skip=68 count=1 2>/dev/null)
echo $((totsize-gptbackup))
1
```

Answer should be `1` (1st GPT is at sector 1, one sector is 512 bytes. GPT Backup location is at byte 32. With `bs=8` 512 -> 64 + 32 -> 4 = 544 -> 68 blocks to skip, GPT Backup is located a end of disk (disk size - 1 block.)... See [GUID Partition Table at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)).

Then

```
read64 gptbackup2 < <(
   dd if=/dev/sda bs=8 skip=$((4+gptbackup*64)) count=1 2>/dev/null)
echo $gptbackup2 
1
```

Answer should be `1` (2nd GPT table, located at end of disk, hold location of 1st GPT table, wich is located at sector `1`)

### Quick small write function...

```
write () { 
    local i=$((${2:-64}/8)) o= v r
    r=$((i-1))
    for ((;i--;)) {
        printf -vv '\%03o' $(( ($1>>8*(0${3+-1}?i:r-i))&255 ))
        o+=$v
    }
    printf "$o"
}
```

This function default to 64 bits, little endian.

```
Usage: write <integer> [bits:64|32|16|8] [switchto big endian]
```

- With two parameter, second parameter must be one of `8`, `16`, `32` or `64`, to be bit length of generated output.
- With any dummy 3th parameter, (even empty string), function will switch to big endian.

.

```
read64 foo < <(write -12345);echo $foo
-12345
```

...

## First post 2015...

#### Upgrade for adding specific bash version (with bashisms)

With new version of `printf` built-in, you could do a lot without having to fork (`$(...)`) making so your script a lot faster.

First let see (by using `seq` and `sed`) how to parse *hd output*:

```
echo ;sed <(seq -f %02g 0 $(( COLUMNS-1 )) ) -ne '
    /0$/{s/^\(.*\)0$/\o0337\o033[A\1\o03380/;H;};
    /[1-9]$/{s/^.*\(.\)/\1/;H};
    ${x;s/\n//g;p}';hd < <(echo Hello good world!)
0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 67 6f  6f 64 20 77 6f 72 6c 64  |Hello good world|
00000010  21 0a                                             |!.|
00000012
```

Were hexadecimal part begin at col 10 and end at col 56, spaced by 3 chars and having one extra space at col 34.

So parsing this could by done by:

```
while read line ;do
    for x in ${line:10:48};do
        printf -v x \\%o 0x$x
        printf $x
      done
  done < <( ls -l --color | hd )
```

#### Old original post

**Edit 2** for Hexadecimal, you could use `hd`

```
echo Hello world | hd
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 6c 64 0a              |Hello world.|
```

or `od`

```
echo Hello world | od -t x1 -t c
0000000  48  65  6c  6c  6f  20  77  6f  72  6c  64  0a
          H   e   l   l   o       w   o   r   l   d  \n
```

shortly

```
while IFS= read -r -n1 car;do [ "$car" ] && echo -n "$car" || echo ; done
```

try them:

```
while IFS= read -rn1 c;do [ "$c" ]&&echo -n "$c"||echo;done < <(ls -l --color)
```

Explain:

```
while IFS= read -rn1 car  # unset InputFieldSeparator so read every chars
    do [ "$car" ] &&      # Test if there is ``something''?
        echo -n "$car" || # then echo them
        echo              # Else, there is an end-of-line, so print one
  done
```

**Edit**; Question was edited: need hex values!?

```
od -An -t x1 | while read line;do for char in $line;do echo $char;done ;done
```

Demo:

```
od -An -t x1 < <(ls -l --color ) |        # Translate binary to 1 byte hex 
    while read line;do                    # Read line of HEX pairs
        for char in $line;do              # For each pair
            printf "\x$char"              # Print translate HEX to binary
      done
  done
```

Demo 2: **We have both hex and binary**

```
od -An -t x1 < <(ls -l --color ) |        # Translate binary to 1 byte hex 
    while read line;do                    # Read line of HEX pairs
        for char in $line;do              # For each pair
            bin="$(printf "\x$char")"     # translate HEX to binary
            dec=$(printf "%d" 0x$char)    # translate to decimal
            [ $dec -lt 32  ] ||           # if caracter not printable
            ( [ $dec -gt 128 ] &&         # change bin to a single dot.
              [ $dec -lt 160 ] ) && bin="."
            str="$str$bin" 
            echo -n $char \               # Print HEX value and a space
            ((i++))                       # count printed values
            if [ $i -gt 15 ] ;then
                i=0
                echo "  -  $str"
                str=""
              fi
      done
  done
```

### New post on september 2016:

This could be usefull on very specific cases, ( I've used them to manualy copy GPT partitions between two disk, at low level, without having `/usr` mounted...)

## Yes, bash could read binary!

... but only one byte, by one... (because `char(0)' couldn't be correctly read, the only way of reading them correctly is to consider *end-of-file*, where if no caracter is read and end of file not reached, then character read is a char(0)).

This is more a proof of concept than a relly usefull tool: there is a ***pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)*** version of `hd` (hexdump).

This use recent *bashisms*, under `bash v4.3` or higher.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf -v ascii \\%o {32..126}
printf -v ascii "$ascii"

printf -v cntrl %-20sE abtnvfr

values=()
todisplay=
address=0
printf -v fmt8 %8s
fmt8=${fmt8// / %02x}

while LANG=C IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 char ;do
    if [ "$char" ] ;then
        printf -v char "%q" "$char"
        ((${#char}==1)) && todisplay+=$char || todisplay+=.
        case ${#char} in
         1|2 ) char=${ascii%$char*};values+=($((${#char}+32)));;
           7 ) char=${char#*\'\\};values+=($((8#${char%\'})));;
           5 ) char=${char#*\'\\};char=${cntrl%${char%\'}*};
                values+=($((${#char}+7)));;
           * ) echo >&2 ERROR: $char;;
        esac
      else
        values+=(0)
      fi
```

```
    if [ ${#values[@]} -gt 15 ] ;then
        printf "%08x $fmt8 $fmt8  |%s|\n" $address ${values[@]} "$todisplay"
        ((address+=16))
        values=() todisplay=
      fi
  done

if [ "$values" ] ;then
        ((${#values[@]}>8))&&fmt="$fmt8 ${fmt8:0:(${#values[@]}%8)*5}"||
            fmt="${fmt8:0:${#values[@]}*5}"
        printf "%08x $fmt%$((
                50-${#values[@]}*3-(${#values[@]}>8?1:0)
            ))s |%s|\n" $address ${values[@]} ''""'' "$todisplay"
fi
printf "%08x (%d chars read.)\n" $((address+${#values[@]})){,}
```

You could try/use this, but don't try to compare performances!

```
time hd < <(seq 1 10000|gzip)|wc
   1415   25480  111711
real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s

time ./hex.sh < <(seq 1 10000|gzip)|wc
   1415   25452  111669
real    0m2.636s
user    0m2.496s
sys     0m0.048s
```

same job: 20ms for `hd` vs 2000ms for my `bash script`.

... but if you wanna read 4 bytes in a file header or even a *sector address* in an hard drive, this could do the job...

Comment: New post: september 2019, introducing `printf %d \"$char`!

Comment: What does `$[blah]` in Bash? When it was introduced? It it the same as `$((expr))`?

Comment: @kyb Yes, my bad; from bash's man page:  *`The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.`*. Answer edited!

Answer (score 10):

Did you try `xxd`? It gives hex dump directly, as you want..

For your case, the command would be:

```
xxd -c 1 /path/to/input_file | while read offset hex char; do
  #Do something with $hex
done
```

Note: extract the char from hex, rather than while read line. This is required because read will not capture white space properly.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

using  `read` a single char can be read at a time as follows:

```
read -n 1 c
echo $c
```

[ANSWER]

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# data file
INPUT=/path/to/input.txt

# while loop
while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do
        # display one character at a time
    echo  "$char"
done < "$INPUT"
```

From this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-read-one-character-atatime-while-loop/)

---

Second method,
Using `awk`, loop through char by char

`awk '{for(i=1;i<=length;i++) print substr($0, i, 1)}' /home/cscape/Desktop/table2.sql`

---

third way,

```
$ fold -1 /home/cscape/Desktop/table.sql  | awk '{print $0}'
```

---

**EDIT**:  To print each char as `HEX` number:

Suppose I have a file name `file` :

```
$ cat file
123A3445F
```

I have written a `awk` script (`named x.awk`) to that read char by char from `file` and print into `HEX` :

```
$ cat x.awk
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN    { _ord_init() }

function _ord_init(    low, high, i, t)
{
    low = sprintf("%c", 7) # BEL is ascii 7
    if (low == "\a") {    # regular ascii
        low = 0
        high = 127
    } else if (sprintf("%c", 128 + 7) == "\a") {
        # ascii, mark parity
        low = 128
        high = 255
    } else {        # ebcdic(!)
        low = 0
        high = 255
    }

    for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        t = sprintf("%c", i)
        _ord_[t] = i
    }
}
function ord(str,    c)
{
    # only first character is of interest
    c = substr(str, 1, 1)
    return _ord_[c]
}

function chr(c)
{
    # force c to be numeric by adding 0
    return sprintf("%c", c + 0)
}

{ x=$0; printf("%s , %x\n",$0, ord(x) )}
```

To write this script I used [awk-documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ordinal-Functions.html)
Now, You can use this `awk` script for your work as follows:

```
$ fold -1 /home/cscape/Desktop/file  | awk -f x.awk
1 , 31
2 , 32
3 , 33
A , 41
3 , 33
4 , 34
4 , 34
5 , 35
F , 46
```

NOTE: `A` value is `41` in HEX decimal. To print in decimal change `%x` to `%d` in last line of script `x.awk`.

Give it a Try!!

Comment: To print in decimal use last line `{ x=$0; printf("%s , %d\n",$0, ord(x) )} `

Comment: you can also use `echo  "$char" | hexdump` in my first example

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, using head, tail and printf:

```
for a in $( seq $( cat file.txt | wc -c ) ) ; do cat file.txt | head -c$a | tail -c1 | xargs -0 -I{} printf '%s %0X\n' {} "'{}" ; done
```

More readable:

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage() {
    echo "Need file with size > 0"
    exit 1
}

test -s "$1" || usage

for a in $( seq $( cat $1 | wc -c ) )
do
    cat $1 | head -c$a | tail -c1 | \
    xargs -0 -I{} printf '%c %#02x\n' {} "'{}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

use `read` with `-n` option.

```
while read -n 1 ch; do
  echo $ch
done < moemoe.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I rather wanted to expand Perleone's own post (as it was *his* basic concept!), my edit was rejected after all, and I was kindly adviced that this should be posted as a separate answer. Fair enough, so I will do that.

Considerations in short for the improvements on Perleone's original script:

- `seq` would be totally overkill here. A simple `while` loop with `a` used as a (likewise simple) counter variable will do the job just fine (and much quicker too)
- The max value, `$(cat $1 | wc -c)` **must** be assigned to a variable, otherwise it will be recalculated every time and make this alternate script run even slower than the one it was derived from.
- There's no need to waste a function on a simple usage info line. However, it is necessary to know about the (mandatory) curly braces around two commands, for without the `{ }`, the `exit 1` command will be executed in either case, and the script interpreter will never make it to the loop. (Last note: `( )` will work too, but not in the same way! Parentheses will spawn a *subshell*, whilst curly braces will execute commands inside them in the *current* shell.)

```
#!/bin/bash

test -s "$1" || { echo "Need a file with size greater than 0!"; exit 1; }

a=0
max=$(cat $1 | wc -c)
while [[ $((++a)) -lt $max ]]; do
  cat $1 | head -c$a | tail -c1 | \
  xargs -0 -I{} printf '%c %#02x\n' {} "'{}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion to give, but would like a feedback from everybody and manly a personal advice from syntaxerror's user.

I don't know much about bash but I thought maybe it would be better to have "cat $1" stored in a variable.. but the problem is that echo command will also bring a small overhead right?

```
test -s "$1" || (echo "Need a file with size greater than 0!"; exit 1)
a=0
rfile=$(cat $1)
max=$(echo $rfile | wc -c)
while [[ $((++a)) -lt $max ]]; do
  echo $rfile | head -c$a | tail -c1 | \
  xargs -0 -I{} printf '%c %#02x\n' {} "'{}"
done
```

in my opinion it would have a better performance but i haven't perf'tested..