# How to decrease TCP connect() system call timeout?

Tags: bash, tcp, connection-timeout

In command below I enable file `/dev/tcp/10.10.10.1/80` both for reading and writing and associate it with file descriptor 3:

```
$ time exec 3<>/dev/tcp/10.10.10.1/80
bash: connect: Operation timed out
bash: /dev/tcp/10.10.10.1/80: Operation timed out

real    1m15.151s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

This automatically tries to perform TCP three-way handshake. If 10.10.10.1 is not reachable as in example above, then `connect` system call tries to connect for 75 seconds. Is this 75 second timeout determined by `bash`? Or is this system default? Last but not least, is there a way to decrease this timeout value?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is determined by TCP. It can be decreased on a per-socket basis by application code.

NB The timeout only takes effect if there is no response at all. If there is a connection refusal, the error occurs immediately.

Comment: I see. Is it also possible to decrease this in `bash`? I guess not.. Probably only in `C`, `python` and other programming languages?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such bash setting.

Answer (score 13):

It's not possible in Bash without modifying the source as already mentioned, although here is the workaround by using `timeout` command, e.g.:

```
$ timeout 1 bash -c "</dev/tcp/stackoverflow.com/80" && echo Port open. || echo Port closed.
Port open.
$ timeout 1 bash -c "</dev/tcp/stackoverflow.com/81" && echo Port open. || echo Port closed.
Port closed.
```

Using this syntax, the `timeout` command will kill the process after the given time.

See: `timeout --help` for more options.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, instead changing the values (not recommended) system widely on `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` is god to know that sending the signal to the parent of the process that open the socket will close it. I was wondering why this works and `$ timeout 1 </dev/tcp/stackoverflow.com/81 && echo Port open.` don't

Answer (score 1):

#### No: there is no way of changing timeout by using `/dev/tcp/`

Yes, you could change default timeout for TCP connection in any programming language.

But, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is not a programming language!

You could have a look into source code (see: [Bash Homepage](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashtop.html)), you may find `lib/sh/netopen.c` file where you could read in `_netopen4` function:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, (typ == 't') ? SOCK_STREAM : SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

You could read this file carefully, there are no consideration of connection timeout.

Without patching bash sources, there is no way of changing connection timeout by a bash script.

#### Simple HTTP client using netcat (near pure bash)

There is a little sample HTTP client written in *pure* bash, but using `netcat`:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp -p $HOME .netbash-XXXXXX)
exec 7> >(nc -w 3 -q 0 stackoverflow.com 80 >$tmpfile)
exec 6<$tmpfile
rm $tmpfile

printf >&7 "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n" \
    /questions/24317341/how-to-decrease-tcp-connect-system-call-timeout

timeout=100;
while ! read -t .001 -u 6 status ; do read -t .001 foo;done
echo STATUS: $status

[ "$status" ] && [ -z "${status//HTTP*200 OK*}" ] || exit 1

echo HEADER:
while read -u 6 -a head && [ "${head//$'\r'}" ]; do
    printf "%-20s : %s\n" ${head%:} "${head[*]:1}"
    done

echo TITLE:
sed '/<title>/s/<[^>]*>//gp;d' <&6

exec 7>&-
exec 6<&-
```

This could render:

```
STATUS: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HEADER:
Cache-Control        : private
Content-Type         : text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options      : SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid       : 46d55dc9-f7fe-425f-a560-fc49d885a5e5
Content-Length       : 91642
Accept-Ranges        : bytes
Date                 : Wed, 19 Oct 2016 13:24:35 GMT
Via                  : 1.1 varnish
Age                  : 0
Connection           : close
X-Served-By          : cache-fra1243-FRA
X-Cache              : MISS
X-Cache-Hits         : 0
X-Timer              : S1476883475.343528,VS0,VE100
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control : off
Set-Cookie           : prov=ff1129e3-7de5-9375-58ee-5f739eb73449; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
TITLE:
bash - How to decrease TCP connect() system call timeout? - Stack Overflow
```

Some explanations:

We create first a temporary file (under private directory for security reason), bind and delete before using them.

```
$ tmpfile=$(mktemp -p $HOME .netbash-XXXXXX)
$ exec 7> >(nc -w 3 -q 0 stackoverflow.com 80 >$tmpfile)
$ exec 6<$tmpfile
$ rm $tmpfile

$ ls $tmpfile
ls: cannot access /home/user/.netbash-rKvpZW: No such file or directory

$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Oct 19 15:20 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Oct 19 15:20 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Oct 19 15:20 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Oct 19 15:20 3 -> /proc/30237/fd
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Oct 19 15:20 6 -> /home/user/.netbash-rKvpZW (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Oct 19 15:20 7 -> pipe:[2097453]

$ echo GET / HTTP/1.0$'\r\n\r' >&7
$ read -u 6 foo
$ echo $foo
HTTP/1.1 500 Domain Not Found

$ exec 7>&-
$ exec 6>&-
```

Comment: Bash is most certainly a programming language.  It's not terribly well-equipped when it comes to networking but that's beside the point.

Comment: @tripleee No, bash is a [tag:shell]. Not basically intended to be a *programming language*... a *command language* or *scripting language*, but not a real *programming language*. see [my *ascii analog clock*](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/13007/9424), specialy why *Don't use this anyway!* And [*how to read binary by using pure bash*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13890319/1765658)... Try this pure bash script and compare performances with C written base64 encoder...

Comment: Meh, po-tah-to po-tay-to. If your criterion is that some things are inconvenient, Pascal and Fortran aren't programming languages, either. C is certainly more general-purpose, but that also means many things are less convenient than in specialized languages.

Comment: @tripleee Did you try to run [ascii-clock.sh](http://fhauri.cartou.ch/ascii-clock/ascii-clock.sh) several hours and check memory usage? (The capitalized `S` at top left mean *sleep*, you could compare with other version on [For geeks:
Ascii-Art analog clock](http://fhauri.cartou.ch/ascii-clock/))

Comment: A memory bug like that sucks, but it's jut an implementation detail. Would you change your opinion if they fixed that problem?

Comment: @tripleee I could workaround by running subtask each seconds, in this case, but bash lack of variable typing, memory garbage and lot or things who exist by default in any progamming language. I insist: programming language and command language are both required, but not same. (I've seen some installation script written under php! It's horrible too!)... Yes: you can use a knife to grab and fork to cut ... but it's not simplier way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126189/discussion-between-f-hauri-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 0):

At the host level, you can change the TCP connect timeout by modifying net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries (default 6). You can observe the exponential backoff by running:

```
for r in {1..6} ; do 
    sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=$r 
    echo predicted: $(( 2**(r+1)-1 )) 
    /bin/time -f %e ./tcp.conn.py 
done
```

output:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 1
predicted: 3
3.02
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 2
predicted: 7
7.02
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 3
predicted: 15
15.03
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 4
predicted: 31
31.06
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5
predicted: 63
63.10
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 6
predicted: 127
127.22
```

tcp.conn.py code:

```
from socket import create_connection

dest_host = '130.1.1.1' # arbitrary IP address
dest_port = 65432       # arbitrary port

try:
    create_connection(
        address=(dest_host, dest_port),
    )
except:
    pass
```

To make the TCP connect timeout as low as possible (3s), run:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=1
```