# How to cat a binary file on a loop

Tags: bash, embedded-linux, cat

I need to read a file and store on another file. For that I use `cat`, the problem is that the file to read is binary, doesnt contain `EOF`, so on this code:

```
for i in $(seq 0 100)
do
  cat < /dev/ttyO5 > $FILE # I'm reading from a serial port, yes
done
```

Cat does never stop, how could I stop it so it goes on the next iteration and so on?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to stop reading before an EOF, how will you know you should stop?  At what point is the `cat` command here "done"?

Comment: That's the question, there's no eof . Im transfering file on a serial cable, the machines are in raw mode, so they dont identify `EOF`

Comment: Are you trying to read just a certain number of bytes, or until a certain pattern is seen, or for a certain amount of time or something like that?  The how to stop is different from knowing when it's time to do so.  Knowing when you want to stop will likely affect the solutions.  For instance, if it's time you might use `timeout`, if it's bytes perhaps you should use `read -n`, etc.  Basically, how would you know it's time to go to the next iteration because you've finished this one?

Comment: I know the amount of bytes im sending, but read is not an option since `null` will be deleted when storing into variable

Comment: The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889659/read-a-file-by-bytes-in-bash) has an approach for reading even `null` in bash if you want to go to that route

Comment: well, thanks for the answer, i already consider that, but im not trying to send byte per byte, i will be sending frames.

Comment: Perhaps `dd` would work for this?  I haven't tried it.

Comment: I did, pipes are the only option to keep `null` and `\n` characters without a fancy solution. But anyway, i solved it, so thanks anyway.

Comment: If you solved it, you should write up and accept your own answer, others may run into the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Put the `cat` in the background.  Add another loop that checks the file size every minute or so. (Whatever you think is a reasonable time.)  If the file has not grown in that time, kill the cat with `kill -9 $!`.

Comment: Since you now tell us that you know the number of bytes, check the number of bytes in the file with `wc -c $file`.  If that matches the number you want to transfer, kill the `cat` process.  If you timeout, check the file size and print an error message if it is not what was expected.