# read binary from stdin with bash

Tags: linux, bash, embedded, sh

I am trying to create small script that would work similar as netcat, but to be able send data over different interfaces in particular CAN bus.
I would like to use this script for different puroses, and also to be able send binary file, or run remote /bin/sh over CAN and so on.

To do this possible I need to read from stdin every byte also "\n", "\r", "\t" and so on, but I do not know how.

I have created such example which is working, but until "\n" is received, script is waiting, but for running /bin/sh I would like to send also "\t\t" for completion and for binary sending as well.

```
while true; do
    # read from stdin single character
    BYTE=$(od -A n -N1 -t x1 | sed 's/ *//g')
    # output to CAN interface  
    cansend $CAN $ADDRESS#$BYTE
done
```

I have also try it this way, but characters as "\n" "\t" are interpreted as zero can frame.

```
while true; do
    { IFS= read -rn1 BYTE ; cansend $CAN $ADDRESS#$(printf "%q" $BYTE | od -A n -t x1 | sed 's/ *//g') ; }
done
```

Of course also queueing bytes would be helpfull

Please keep in mind that I am using it on embedded system without python or possibility to download any special commands.

Comment: Shell is not the right tool for binary data. The shell is geared to manipulate characters streams across commands. Add quotes around your `"$BYTE"` variable reference to avoid unwanted `$'\n\t '` splitting and globbing patterns to file names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a file by bytes in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889659/read-a-file-by-bytes-in-bash)

Comment: While you can probably get around it, shell scripting is heavily line-oriented.  Especially if you want "live" input that doesn't wait for a newline you probably want to look at moving to something else - python for example might fit your needs (though with python3 you do need to worry about omnipresent unicode support confusing things)

Comment: Another option is to make a C program - or to modify an existing one. Just one idea (out of plenty of others): The free CANopen implementation [CanFestival](https://canfestival.org/) comes together with some example programs for PC (Win/Linux) that put data into a CAN driver that has already been integrated (look for "CANopenShell"). You could modify that application to get a suitable solution to your problem quite quickly.