# In Bash how to convert string number to binary form uint32_t as it is stored in memory?

Tags: bash

The most simplest task in C become a problem in Bash for me.

```
echo 4455 | convert_bin 
DU
```

It is possible with

```
echo \x44\x55
```

But I have to convert a 4 byte number.

As output I would like to see RAW data.

In C there is a function `scanf()`.

In C++ I can write:

```
uint32_t ui;
std::cin >> ui;
```

I want to operate with that 4 bytes to store them with dd to certain place in memory. Never thought this could be so hard in Bash

Comment: You need to define your problem in terms of bash, if you want to solve it in bash. For instance, after doing the conversion and storing the result in a bash variable `ui` , what do you expect a `echo $ui` to output? C++ has integers, bash has only strings, so you need to define any problem in terms of strings.

Comment: Here is an answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889659/read-a-file-by-bytes-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
 perl -e 'print pack "H4", shift' 4455
```

[shift](http://p3rl.org/shift) picks up the argument, [print](http://p3rl.org/print) prints it. [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack) is used for various type conversions, `H4` stays for "4 bytes in hex".

You can also use various hexdump tools, e.g.

```
xxd -r <<< '0 4455'
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I do not need HEX, i need RAW data.

Comment: What do you mean by raw data? Both the commands return `DU`.

Comment: The form it is stored in memory like C type uint32_t

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: 4 raw machine bytes

Comment: `xxd -r <<< '0 44553'` drops the 3

Comment: What do you mean by "4 raw machine bytes"? Can you show what the output of the command should be for `4455` when run through `cat -v`?

Comment: @kyp : You don't have raw memory bytes in shell! You can manipulate raw bytes in a file (for instance using `dd`), but you have no real control of the bit pattern in a shell variable, except via the encoding, and this is in effect shown by the excellent solution presented by choroba.

Comment: I agree. This is not task for shell. Will work with text as it is simpler