# bash: binary XOR one file with another

Tags: bash, file, binaryfiles, xor

I have two files, I want to perform a byte-by-byte XOR on these and output the result.

It's trivial to do in most languages, but I'd prefer to have this as a bash script and I'm not quite sure how to process the files 'byte by byte'. Performance is not an issue, they're typically small (less than 4 KB) files.

I would like the output to have the same size as the 1st input file. If the 2nd file is larger, skip the remaining part, if the 2nd file is smaller I'd like to 'wrap around' i.e. reread from the start until the size of the 1st file is met.

Output can simply go to stdout (can pipe that elsewhere if necessary).

The specific points that I'm struggling with:

1. How do I open a file for binary reading in bash
2. How do I process the two files byte-by-byte, XOR'ing each byte with the corresponding byte from the other file (perhaps read both files as an array?)
3. Can I easily do the wrapping around for the 2nd file, I'd do this by taking the index modulo its size but I'm not quite sure how to express the modulo

Comment: How strong is that "preference" for bash? It's possible, but going to be very verbose and inefficient. (I'm thinking about creating an associative array as a lookup table for pairs of hex digits). It'll not just be slower code, but longer and harder-to-read code; and Stack Overflow _is_ aimed at "practical" questions, so some legitimate reason to choose bash over other interpreters built into the base install of common distros would be welcome.

Comment: (also, bash doesn't have something like a `char` type that can store all possible characters including a NUL; so you end up with either ugly hacks to handle NUL bytes or hex-encoding on the input side, which just makes everything that much slower).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the feedback, the preference is partially for portability (so I can use this on different systems without further dependencies), and also for me to learn from so I gain more understanding how to approach such situations with bash in general. And just like you say, since there is no `char` or `8 bit integer` type in bash, I'm clueless how to properly store the data and perform operations on it.

Comment: What you end up stuck with is strings, with an empty / zero-byte string representing the NUL if you aren't encoding your data (hex/octal/etc) beforehand. There _are_ common tools for that encoding, though, so it's quite doable.

Comment: ...from a _portability_ perspective, I'd argue that these days Python is good enough; it's been a pretty much universal out-of-the-box component for decades now if you make your code compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Anyhow, if you want to read a single byte, spend some time playing with the behavior of `IFS= read -r -n 1 -d '' nextbyte`. Pay attention to its `$?` in addition to what it leaves in `$nextbyte` -- you need to be able to distinguish between the read-a-NUL case and the failed-to-read case.

Comment: And if when you say "bash" you really mean "standard command-line tools", I'd consider implementing this as a pure awk program instead of using bash at all; doubly so if you're only targeting platforms with GNU awk (and if you needed more portability than that, you probably also couldn't assume bash 4.0+ and so wouldn't have associative arrays, making a bash implementation much more cumbersome than it would be otherwise as well).

Comment: ...one place to start might be [Read a file byte-by-byte in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889659/read-a-file-by-bytes-in-bash); that plus knowledge of associative arrays (as an option for building lookup tables) may actually get you far enough to be able to ask a more narrowly-scoped question.