# Convert a file of decimal numbers to the ASCII equivalent

Tags: linux, bash, printf, sh, od

I can convert a text file to a list of ASCII decimals like this:

```
$ echo "hello" | od -An -td1 -v -w1
  104
  101
  108
  108
  111
   10
```

What is the inverse operation? How can I convert the file of decimals back to text? I want to use only common Unix command-line tools. I've been looking at `printf` but haven't figured out how to make it work.

Comment: `while read -r dec; do printf -v oct '%03o' "$dec"; printf "\\$oct"; done <decimals.txt`

Comment: Have a look at this answer: [Read a file by bytes in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13890319/1765658)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the *printf* function using the parameter "%c" that treats the input as a single character.

**Easy solution**: Pipe the output to the inverse function.

```
echo "hello" | od -An -td1 -v -w1 | awk '{ printf "%c", $1 }'
```

awk receives the piped information in the first column with ASCII value and sends it as input for the print function.

Comment: That works. Thank you. Why doesn't `echo "hello" | od -An -td1 -v -w1 | while read x; do printf "%c" $x; done` work?

Comment: @user448810 The bash printf is a bit inconcistent and will only use the first character of every word. It does not perform the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
perl -ne'print( chr( $_ ) )'
```

```bash
perl -ne'print chr'
```

```bash
perl -pe'$_ = chr'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)