# get a part of a binary file using gnu-coreutils, bash

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-coreutils

I want to get a part of a binary file, from byte #480161397 to #480170447 (included, 9051 bytes in total)

I use `cut -b`, and I expected the size of trunk1.gz to be 9051 bytes, but I get a different result.

```
$ wget https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2016-07/segments/1454701152097.59/warc/CC-MAIN-20160205193912-00264-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.gz

$ cut -b480161397-480170447 CC-MAIN-20160205193912-00264-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.gz >trunk1.gz

$ echo $((480170447-480161397+1))
9051

$ ls -l trunk1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 david  staff     3400324 Sep  8 10:28 trunk1.gz
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you do a `wc -c trunk1.gz`?

Comment: 3400324 trunk1.gz

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423346/how-do-i-extract-a-single-chunk-of-bytes-from-within-a-file

Comment: That means your cut is not doing what you thought it should. I tried `cut -b` with some `.gz` files that I had as well. I also got file sizes larger than the bbytes specified. In normal files this can be explained by the fact that there are columns in the files. So the command `cut -b` picks out the corresponding bytes from each line. Hence large file sizes. i.e. `cut -b` is probably not what you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with binary, I advise you to use `dd` command.

```
dd if=trunk1.gz bs=1 skip=480161397 count=9051 of=output.bin
```

`bs` is the block size and is set to 1 byte.

Comment: `dd if=CC-MAIN-20160205193912-00264-ip-10-236-182-209.ec2.internal.warc.gz bs=1 skip=$((480161397-1)) count=9051 of=trunk1.gz`

Answer (score 2):

`cut -bN-M` copies the range `N-M` bytes from ***every*** line of the input.

**Example**:

```
$ cut -b4-7 <<END
0123456789
abcdefghij
ABCDEFGHIJ
END
```

**Output**:

```
3456
defg
DEFG
```

Consider using `dd` for your purposes.