# Hex Editing From A Bash File

Tags: bash

I need to know how to hex edit from a bash file. For example,

```
hedit 0x0 A
```

This would write A to offset 0x0

Comment: Add this line in bash file and run bash file.I think.

Comment: That isn't a real command. I need a real command.

Comment: You may be better off inlining some python for this. Bash doesn't work well with binary data, especially NUL bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `dd` to overwrite parts of a file like this:

```
printf '\x0a' | dd of=filetopatch bs=1 seek=0 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

The meaning of the arguments are:

- `of=filetopatch` : the file to patch (the output file)
- `bs=1` : change 1 byte at a time
- `seek=0` : move to offset 0 (decimal) before writing
- `count=1` : copy only 1 input block
- `conv=notrunc` : do not truncate the output after the edit

Comment: What if I want to store the offset to a variable?

Comment: You are using bash, so use `offset=100` and then instead of `seek=100`  use `seek=$offset`

Comment: I meant load what that offset contains. (Ex: 0A)

Comment: That's not the offset but the data. By the way you can use the option `if=inputfile` of `dd` and skip everything up to the `|`. Check [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)

Comment: I know how to use dd. How do I get the data from a specific offset?

Comment: That's a different question and should be posted as a separate one. But you could check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272675/how-to-grab-an-arbitrary-chunk-from-a-file-on-unix-linux)